# Using a local file in html for a PyQt5 webengine

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, plotly, qwebengineview

I am trying to embed a plotly graph into a PyQt5 webengine view. I was able to do so using the following:

[open plotly in qwebview in interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866958/open-plotly-in-qwebview-in-interactive-mode)

If you read it, the article explains that you can't directly include the javascript in the HTML when using the webengine view (it has issues loading files above 2 MB). However, I'm trying to make it so that the source for the javascript is a local copy of plotly-min.js (saved in the project folder) so that anyone using the program doesn't need an internet connection to view the graphs it generates. I've tried to follow a few examples on html, but to no avail.

The original code that does work with an internet connection is:

```
raw_html = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />'
raw_html += '<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head>'
raw_html += '<body>'
raw_html += plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
raw_html += '</body></html>'

temp_view = QWebEngineView()
temp_view.setHtml(graph)
```

If I understand it correctly, I need to change this part:

```
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js">
```

I've already tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/Users/UserName/PycharmProjects/ProjectFolder/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

I honestly do not know HTML. This is the only HTML in the code (the rest is in Python 3). Does anyone know why the above might not work and what I need to change? I have a suspicion I might somehow be running into the 2 MB limit the above question referenced, as different variations I've found online for how to reference a local file in HTML don't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many browsers for security reason disable the loading of local files, but as noted in the following [forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/60691/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-for-iframe-how-to-disable-web-security/4) you can enable that capability with:

```
sys.argv.append("--disable-web-security")
```

Assuming the .js is next to your .py file:

```
.
├── main.py
└── plotly-latest.min.js
```

you can use the following example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, QUrl

import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

sys.argv.append("--disable-web-security")
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

x1 = [10, 3, 4, 5, 20, 4, 3]
trace1 = go.Box(x = x1)
layout = go.Layout(showlegend = True)
data = [trace1]

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout = layout)

path = QDir.current().filePath('plotly-latest.min.js') 
local = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path).toString()

raw_html = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />'
raw_html += '<script src="{}"></script></head>'.format(local)
raw_html += '<body>'
raw_html += plotly.offline.plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
raw_html += '</body></html>'

view = QWebEngineView()
view.setHtml(raw_html)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: if one wants run this under Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA driver then you need following dependencies: `PyQt5 == 5.10.0
PyOpenGL
plotly`. And add `if sys.platform.startswith( 'linux' ) :
    from OpenGL import GL` to the script. This avoids two different issues (Not finding QtWebEngineWidgets and shader load problems).

Comment: @swiesend 
post it as an answer :D

Comment: I try the code above in Win10 with python 3.7.4 and shows nothing. only a empty window. I downloaded latest ".js" from https://plotly.com/javascript/getting-started/ , Both ".js" and .py files in same directory. What wrong here?

Comment: it is working with `raw_html += '<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script></head>'`but fail to when using  `raw_html += '<script src="{}"></script></head>'.format(local)`

Answer (score 2):

In case it's helpful to anybody, I went a different direction with a solution. Instead of relying on the `QWebEngineView.setHTML` method, I decided to use a named temporary file to write the html to the disk, then load that into a `QUrl` to load into the `QWebEngineView` using the `QUrl.fromLocalFile` and `QWebEngineView.setUrl` methods.

Altogether I applied this into a custom `PlotlyWidget` class, so here's the full thing in case it's helpful to anyone.

Some special care had to be taken to ensure the temporary files get deleted when the `PlotlyWiget` goes out of scope and gets garbage collected (i.e. the `__del__` override).

```py
import os
import tempfile
import plotly
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

class PlotlyWidget(QWebEngineView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.plotly_fig = None
        self.html_file = None

    def load_fig(self, plotly_fig):
        self.plotly_fig = plotly_fig
        self.plotly_fig.update_layout(font={'size':18})
        self.update_fig()

    def update_fig(self):
        html = '<html><body>'
        html += plotly.offline.plot(self.plotly_fig, output_type='div', include_plotlyjs=True)
        html += '</body></html>'

        if self.html_file is not None: # close previous tempfiles so that they delete from disk properly
            self.html_file.close()
            os.unlink(self.html_file.name)

        self.html_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.html', delete=False)
        with open(self.html_file.name, 'w') as file:
            file.write(html)
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.html_file.name)
        self.setUrl(url)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """Delete the temp file on close event."""
        super().closeEvent(event)
        if self.html_file is not None:
            self.html_file.close()
            os.unlink(self.html_file.name)
            self.html_file = None

    def __del__(self):
        """Handle temp file close (and deletion) if QWebEngineView is garbage collected instead of closed."""
        if self.html_file is not None:
            self.html_file.close()
            os.unlink(self.html_file.name)
```

Typical usage is then to generate a plotly figure and then send it to the `load_fig` method like:

```py
# from within QMainWindow or other QWidget instance
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_scatter(y=ydata, x=xdata)

    self.ploty_widget = PlotlyWidget()
    self.ploty_widget.load_fig(fig)
    self.ploty_widget.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems running the example of @eyllanesc under Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 with NVIDIA driver.

First I had to downgrade `PyQt5` `5.10.1` to `5.10.0` to avoid:

```
[0525/114545.216138:WARNING:stack_trace_posix.cc(648)] Failed to open file: /home/tmp/.gl5Qb0Tf (deleted)
  Error: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Could not find QtWebEngineProcess
[3032:3032:0525/114545.495351:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(182)] Check failed: ReceiveFixedMessage(fds[0], kZygoteBootMessage, sizeof(kZygoteBootMessage), &boot_pid). 
...
```

But this should be fixed for the future in [`PyQt5 5.11`](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/3015#issuecomment-386230505)

The second problem was the linking of the shader (`ubuntu 16.04`):

```
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(qt_Matrix): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
shader compilation failed:
```

Under `ubuntu 18.04` in `VirtualBox`:

```
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000000
#0 0x7faa83f029a5 <unknown>
#1 0x7faa82c42501 <unknown>
#2 0x7faa83f02d3d <unknown>
#3 0x7faa9228a890 <unknown>
  r8: 0000000000000001  r9: 0000000002d5d3d0 r10: 0000000000000002 r11: 00007faa8ec4a000
 r12: 0000000002d386b0 r13: 0000000002d59b50 r14: 0000000000000000 r15: 00007faa8ed3b280
  di: 0000000000001f01  si: 00007faa8ed3d210  bp: 0000000002d52e40  bx: 0000000000000001
  dx: 0000000002e52220  ax: 0000000002e52220  cx: 0000000000000000  sp: 00007ffce38c2b78
  ip: 0000000000000000 efl: 0000000000010202 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000014
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

that can be solved by following the advise of [dcortesi](https://forum.qt.io/post/405366) fixing an 4 year old Ubuntu bug:

```
if sys.platform.startswith( 'linux' ) :
    from OpenGL import GL
```

**Putting it all togehter:**

`requirements.txt`

```
PyQt5 == 5.10.0
PyOpenGL
plotly
```

`webview.py`

```
import sys

if sys.platform.startswith( 'linux' ) :
    from OpenGL import GL

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, QUrl

import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

sys.argv.append("--disable-web-security")
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

x1 = [10, 3, 4, 5, 20, 4, 3]
trace1 = go.Box(x = x1)
layout = go.Layout(showlegend = True)
data = [trace1]

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout = layout)

path = QDir.current().filePath('plotly-latest.min.js') 
local = QUrl.fromLocalFile(path).toString()

raw_html = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" />'
raw_html += '<script src="{}"></script></head>'.format(local)
raw_html += '<body>'
raw_html += plotly.offline.plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
raw_html += '</body></html>'

view = QWebEngineView()
view.setHtml(raw_html)
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

One can download the the latest plotly.js [here](https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js). I used `plotly.js v1.38.0` for this example.